# Remove black background on canvas in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, qr-code

I am displaying the qr-code on the screen using the [qrcode.react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode.react) library in react. It displays correctly on the srceen with white backgroung and I can scan it as well.

The Qr code renderer code:

```
{qrCodeDataUrl && (
    <QRCodeCanvas
      value={qrCodeDataUrl}
      size={350}
      className="qr-code"
      imageSettings={{
        src: "/media/logos/favicon.ico",
        height: 64,
        width: 128,
        excavate: true,
      }}
      level="H"
    />
)}
```

I also have a download button where users can download that QR code. but when it is downloaded, the background is transparent (black). so that I cannot scan it. How to make the background white?

I have tried some solutions, like setting the bgColor property on the `QRCodeCanvas` element to white and styling the qrcode component as well in the div but it is not working.

The download function:

```
  const downloadQRCode = (url: string) => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector(".qr-code") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = dataUrl;
    downloadLink.download = "qr-code.png";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default color of a canvas is transparent, and it seems that your background is black, so you need to give the canvas you are creating a white background color.

For example:

```
 const downloadQRCode = (url: string) => {
    var canvas = document.querySelector(".qr-code") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");

    // Create a new off-screen canvas with the same dimensions as the original canvas
    const offscreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    offscreenCanvas.width = 200;
    offscreenCanvas.height = 200;
    
    // Get the context of the off-screen canvas
    const offscreenContext = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d');
    
    // Set the background color of the off-screen canvas
    offscreenContext.fillStyle = '#fff';
    offscreenContext.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

    // Draw the original canvas onto the off-screen canvas
    offscreenContext.drawImage(image, 30, 30);
    
    const dataUrl = offscreenCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"); 
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = dataUrl;
    downloadLink.download = "qr-code.png";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  };
```

**Update**:
The correct and simple way is simply to add `includeMargin`.

```
{qrCodeDataUrl && (
    <QRCodeCanvas
      value={qrCodeDataUrl}
      size={350}
      className="qr-code"
      imageSettings={{
        src: "/media/logos/favicon.ico",
        height: 64,
        width: 128,
        excavate: true,
      }}
      level="H"
      includeMargin={true}
    />
)}
```

Comment: Nah, the whole image turned black now. Tried white as well.

Comment: I mistakenly wrote black instead of white, I corrected the answer, try now `context.fillStyle = "white";`.

Comment: I want "white" background.

Comment: I made some changes, please try again. You can also see it at https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-sound-lt9gb0?file=/src/App.js